# Internally created variables, as part of the query or as parameters in preparedStatement?

Tags: java, prepared-statement

Imagine that we have a method like this. Should the internally created parameters of the query set as parameters in the preparedStatement or should they go as part of the query?

```
public int countActives(int panelId) {
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        int count = 0;
        int todayInt = Date.DatToInt(new GregorianCalendar());
        ResultSet rs = null;
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append(" SELECT count(po.object_id)");
        sql.append(" FROM po, n, a");
        sql.append(" WHERE po.id = ?");
        sql.append(" AND po.id = n.id");
        sql.append(" AND po.id = a.id");
        sql.append(" AND ?");
        sql.append(" between a.from_date and a.to_date");
        sql.append(" AND n.object_type = ");
        sql.append(ObjectType.CLASS);
        try {
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
            stmt.setInt(1, panelId);
            stmt.setInt(2, todayInt);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                count = rs.getInt(1);
            }
            return count;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

In this method, it can be seen that todayInt is always independent from the parameters, but it is passed to preparedStatement as a parameter. And the ObjectType.CLASS is set directly in the query, not as a parameter.

```
public class ObjectType {
    public static final int CLASS = 2;
}
```

More precise, should todayInt go in the query and not as parameter? Is something about the design, or would be better for the performance?

```
sql.append(" AND ");
sql.append(todayInt);
sql.append(" between a.from_date and a.to_date");
```

Comment: It doesn't help that we have no idea what `ObjectType.CLASS` is...

Comment: Sorry, ObjectType.CLASS is a constant value (String or Enum)

Comment: With what value? In particular, is it something like `'Foo'` or does it refer to a different field within the query?

Comment: The value of ObjectType.CLASS is "Foo"

Comment: So your query ends up ending with `AND n.object_type = Foo` rather than `AND n.object_type = 'Foo'`? If so, you couldn't use a parameter for that anyway...

Comment: Sorry again, I checked and ObjectType.CLASS = 2

Comment: In this case it might be worthwile considering using `CURRENT_DATE()`, `NOW()` or whatever SQL function. Having SQL literals allows collecting them declarative, in xml, as mybatis.

Answer (score 0):

The reason to use PreparedStatement is, PreparedStatement can be compiled in client(JDBC) and in DB server. (Maybe some difference for different DB and JDBC driver.) And then the pre compiled statement can be reused, like a template. During execution, he params will be passed to that compiled statement. Then it will improve the performance a lot.

So, if only the parameters are variable, you should use prepared statement and parameter for that variable.

But, there are also some constraints:
  1. PreparedStatement will retain some resource, so there will be problem if there are too many of them. In your example, if you use as this:

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append(" SELECT count(po.object_id)");
    sql.append(" FROM po, n, a");
    sql.append(" WHERE po.id = ?");
    sql.append(" AND po.id = n.id");
    sql.append(" AND po.id = a.id");
    sql.append(" AND "),append(todayInt);
    sql.append(" between a.from_date and a.to_date");
    sql.append(" AND n.object_type = ");
    sql.append(ObjectType.CLASS);
    try {
        stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        stmt.setInt(1, panelId);
        ......
```

The `todayInt`  is one part of PreparedStatement, so, for every value of `todayInt`, there will be one PreparedStatement. If there are many values of `todayInt`, there will be too many PreparedStatement. Then it is not good.

2. Another constraint is, you can not set some kind of condition as parameter, for example:

   sql = "SELECT * FROM ?"
   stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
   stmt.setInt(1, tableName);

It is illegal, at least for some DB JDBC implementation.